How do I change user.config settings appdata folder?
I'm wondering how I can change the folder of my user.config stored settings folder from the name of the application to the name of the company. For example I want to change %appdata%\AppName\AppName.exe_StrongName_ to %appdata%\CompanyName\AppName.exe_StrongName_. Is there anyway I'm able to do that???
I have not tried anything at all because I knew that nothing would've worked for me. So how am I able to do that?

How can you know that nothing will work when you have not tried anything, what's stopping you from just moving that file from %appdata%\AppName to %appdata%\CompanyName?

I've just not taken risks cause I was afraid of losing my project. I haven't really taken much risks after I changed the framework of my projects. Also nothing is really stopping me from moving it, it's just it wont save it to the new folder I moved it to.

The new folder probably has policies against moving .exe files to it, this might be SuperUser territory rather than a software problem.

I’m not talking about moving the EXE file, I’m talking about saving the user.config file to a different location. :/

There will be no risks if you just copy paste that user.config file somewhere before moving it to %appdata%\CompanyName. You will not lose it even if the move fails because you have a backup copy. Making a backup copy will cost almost nothing because config file sizes are usually very negligible

What I’m trying to say is I want the user.config application settings to be saved at %appdata%\CompanyName and not %appdata%\AppName. I want the CompanyName folder in Appdata to be where the user.config is saved generated and stored instead of it being the Application Name

In that case you can refer Setting File Location documentation. Seems like you can change the location by updating the Application.LocalUserAppData property

Alright! How do I update Application.LocalUserAppData? What file do I edit to update that? Or if I even need to edit a file.

What kind of application is this? Do you have access to the codebase? Do you have Visual Studios?

Okay nvm I just realized this WHOLE time I had to just add the company name in the assembly and not modify anything else.

This WHOLE time I realized I had to enter a company name in the Assembly Information in the Application Tab that’s in the Project Properties window… Wow I’ve asked this question for nothing. ‍♂️
Well hey atleast some kid will know why their settings saving to %AppData%/MyApp folder and not %AppData%/CompanyName. ‍♂️
